# Como acelerar o Android Studio + Gradle?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Estou passando o maior sufoco ao usar o Android Studio devido à demora no processo de compilação do projeto. Quais configurações melhoram o desempenho do Android Studio + Gradle?

Comment: Não é minha área de programação, mas como norma geral, é legal fornecer o máximo de detalhes do seu *setup*, assim fica mais fácil dar um diagnóstico acertado. Pode ver mais detalhes em [ask]. Boa sorte!

Comment: Quantos Giga de RAM estão disponíveis no computador?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem algumas configurações que podem ajudar a dar uma acelerada no processo de `build` do **Gradle**:

1. Usar sempre as últimas versões do Android Studio, Gradle Plugin e do Gradle.
2. Realizar as seguintes configurações:

   - Configurar seu processo de build usand o `daemon` do Gradle (diminui o tempo de inicialização do [processo que faz o `build`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)). Já que com o `deamon` o processo não vai precisar ser inicializado sempre (apenas na primeira vez).
   - Habilitar o build em paralelo (faz com que o módulos independentes sejam compilados em paralelo). Essa configuração é boa se seu computador tiver mais de um núcleo.
   - Ajustar a memória usada pelo Gradle.

   Tudo isso através do `gradle.properties`.

   Você tanto pode configurar no seu `gradle.properties` da raiz de seu projeto ou globalmente no `seu_home/.gradle/gradle.properties`.

   ```
   # Project-wide Gradle settings.

   # IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
   # Settings specified in this file will override any Gradle settings
   # configured through the IDE.

   # For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
   # http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

   # The Gradle daemon aims to improve the startup and execution time of Gradle.
   # When set to true the Gradle daemon is to run the build.
   # TODO: disable daemon on CI, since builds should be clean and reliable on servers
   org.gradle.daemon=true

   # Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
   # The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
   # Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

   # When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
   # This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
   # http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
   org.gradle.parallel=true

   # Enables new incubating mode that makes Gradle selective when configuring     projects. 
   # Only relevant projects are configured which results in faster builds for large multi-projects.
   # http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand
   org.gradle.configureondemand=true
   ```

   Ou pelas configurações pelo *Settings* do *Android Studio*:

[image: Settings do Android Studio]

3. Não usar a funcionalidade de **auto-import** do *Android Studio*, existe um [bug não resolvido](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59965) que deixa a *IDE* mais lenta.
4. Usar o modo `offline` do *Android Studio*, ignorando checagens por update das dependências:

[image: Localização da configuração de modo offline]

## Referências

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500539/3404639
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23648341/3404639

Comment: Valeu, Wakim. Foi direto ao assunto e não ficou enrolando perguntando quanto de RAM minha máquina tem. Vou fazer essas configurações. Obrigado.

Comment: @Wakim, não adiantou muito as configurações :(, acho que o jeito vai ser um upgrade mesmo

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino, realmente com a quantidade de bibliotecas que usamos, o build se torna muito pesado. Lembrando que cada um delas precisa passar pelo processo de build junto com o apk para se criar o DEX. A um tempo atrás o google começou um nova nova ferramenta de build chamada Jack and Jill, que ainda está bem experimental (não tendo muitos recursos como processamento de anotações) que tende a reduzir o build time. Outra solução que geralmente ajuda é sempre estar com a última versão do Gradle (atual 2.6), ai basta verificar no seu gradle-wrapper.properties.

Comment: Então @Wakim, eu uso o AS todo dia no trabalho não tenho problemas, em casa que estou trabalhando num aplicativo que fiquei com essa dúvida, mas eu joguei mais 8gb e está tranquilo agora haha, valeu pelo comentário! Go Android!

Comment: @Wakim muito obrigado, ótima resposta!

Comment: Excelente resposta. Acelerou muito o Build.